# "message": "Creating default object from empty value", in postman

Tags: json, laravel, header, response, key-value

```
public function addcart($request)
    {
        $patient_id = config('api.current_user.patient_id') ? config('api.current_user.patient_id') : 0;
        $patient = Patient::find($patient_id);
        $patient_diagnostic_cart = @unserialize($patient->diagnostic_cart);
        $response = [];
       
        if (!empty($patient_diagnostic_cart)) {
            
            if (in_array((int)$request->test_id, $patient_diagnostic_cart)) {

               
                // abort(400, "Test allready added");
                $message = "Test allready added";
            } else {
                array_push($patient_diagnostic_cart, (int)$request->test_id);
                $patient->diagnostic_cart = serialize($patient_diagnostic_cart);
                $patient->save();
                $message = "Test added";
            }
        } else {
            $patient_diagnostic_cart = (array)(int)$request->test_id;
            $patient->diagnostic_cart = serialize($patient_diagnostic_cart);
            $message = "Test  added";
            $patient->save();
        }
        $response = [
            'message' => $message,
            'test_id' => array_values(unserialize($patient->diagnostic_cart)),
        ];
        $data =  json_decode(json_encode($response, true));
        return $data;
    }
```